# Why is it impossible to pass mutex to function through Call-by-Value?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

[Full source code](https://onlinegdb.com/ByZ_s3T1BB)

If I pass mutex object to `worker()` without reference, it causes compile error.

```
void worker(int& p_counter, std::mutex p_mutex) {
    ...
}

=============================================================================

workers.push_back(std::thread(worker, std::ref(counter), mutex));
```

But if I pass it with reference, it is compiled well.

```
void worker(int& p_counter, std::mutex& p_mutex) {
    ...
}

=============================================================================

workers.push_back(std::thread(worker, std::ref(counter), std::ref(mutex)));
```

Why is mutex implemented to be passed to functions using references?

Comment: Mutex doesn't have a copy constructor, thus you can't.

Comment: What does "value" mean when you are talking about a mutex? The whole point of a mutex is to prevent two threads from locking the _same_ mutex at the same time. In other words, what's important is the _identity_ of the mutex.

Comment: A mutex is like a road signal. Cars are not supposed to copy or carry these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I pass mutex object to `worker()` without reference, it causes compile error

That's because `std::mutex` is a non-copyable class.

> Why is mutex implemented to be passed to functions using references?

There is no reason to pass an object of `std::mutex` by value (and therefore copying it) as a mutex should be used for mutual exclusion to prevent race conditions (a function that receives it should be able to refer to the same mutex object as the one passed by the caller).

Answer (score 3):

Because it makes no sense and doesn't serve the purpose of a mutex.

Lets say you could send a mutex by value (i.e. mutex had a copy constructor). A copy is passed and mutex is locked... its the copy that is locked. There's no guarantee that you are preventing race conditions. Thus, copy constructor is not present and it can't be send by value.